# How answer could be 433?

Tags: c++

The answer of this code is 433. How it can be possible. I was thinking that answer is 273.

```
int x(int &a,int &b)
{
    a=3;
    b=4;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int a=2;
    int b=7;
    int c=x(b,a);
    cout<<a<<b<<c;
}
```

Answer: 433

Comment: it's mindscrew code swapping both variables in a different namespace. Just follow the execution/print values.

Comment: btw your expected answer sounds like you dont know what pass-by-reference means. If thats the case, google it ;)

Comment: The `a` inside the function `x` is not the same `a` as the `a` in `main`. Change the two `a`s in `main` to `a1` and change the two `b`s in `main` to `b1` and things will be much clearer.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the function step by step, comments refering to the variables in main, then this it what happens:

```
int x(int &a,int &b) {      // note: pass-by-reference !
    a=3;                    // b = 3
    b=4;                    // a = 4
    return a;               // return 3
}

c = x(b,a);                 // c = 3
cout << a << b << c;        // prints 433
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing references to x method, instead of copies of values, so after calling method a and b will change. That's why result is 433.

Answer (score 1):

In the function, `c` gets assigned the value 3, `a` gets assigned the value 4 and `b` gets assigned the value `3`. Please note that through the crappily written code, the parameter `a` in the function is actually `b` in main, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the output as `433` is [pass-by-reference.](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

In-order to avoid confusion for you, I have changed the parameters of the `function x` as `inA` and `inB`.

```
int x(int &inA,int &inB)
{
    inA=3;
    inB=4;
    return inA;
}

int main()
{
    int a=2;
    int b=7;
    int c=x(b,a);
    cout<<a<<b<<c;
}
```

Now, when the following call is made `int c = x(b,a)`, you can imagine as if `inA` is a reference to `b` and `inB` to `a`.

So, when `inA = 3`( when `inA` is set to 3, it actually alters the value of `b` to 3.

Similarly, when `inB = 4`, `a` is set to 4.

`c` is assigned the returning value (i.e 3).

Therefore, we have `a=4`, `b=3` and `c=3`. Hence, it prints `433`.